# Server Side Rendering not updating view source and for other routes view source shows 404 could not get url

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I followed steps as in this link for server side rendering
https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/server-side-rendering-reactjs
but still not working

I tried to create webpack.server.js like this. when npm server:start its showing view source as normal react

````
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'development',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: './server/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,    
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['','.js', '.jsx']
  },
};```
````